# How to calculate the fourth variable in an equation given any three?

Tags: python

First of all I declare that **I'm really new** in this coding world.

I'm trying to write a "program" that allow me to find all variables involved in simple interest calculation.
I wrote the **basic version** and is working well.

```
PV = float(input("Present value: "))
R = float(input("Rate %: "))
N = float(input("Time in days: "))
FV = PV + (PV * N * R) / 365
print ((), round(FV,2))
```

But, in fact, I'm looking a bit beyond the `FV` formula. That is a program that allow me to ask **ANY** of the four variables (PV,R,N,FV), given the other three. My mind looks at HP calculators that gives you the variable that you need given the other three.
I'm not thinking of something like a solver because I want to develop the program with the basic python tools, just to exercise the challenge.
I tried with `if` and `else` but it didn't work.
As far as I checked "lists" is not a useful option, but I didn't try.

Comment: `FV = PV + (PV * N * R) / 365` is not an equation, but rather than assignment: you *must* know the values on the right in order to get a value for the left. Some languages (MetaFont is the one that I'm most familiar with) do allow you to write equations where any *one* unknown can be given a value based on the known values. In Python, you'll need a library like SciPy to do similar equation solving automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I think a sample program could look something like this:

```
from typing import Union


def input_float(text: str) -> Union[float, None]:
    """
    Inputs a float from user
    """

    s = input(text).strip()
    return float(s) if s != "" else None


def input_values() -> tuple:
    """
    Inputs values from user, validate inputs
    """
    PV = input_float("Present value: ")
    R = input_float("Rate %: ")
    N = input_float("Time in days: ")
    FV = input_float("Future value: ")

    if len([i for i in [PV, R, N, FV] if i is not None]) != 3:
        raise ValueError("Invalid user input: exactly one value should be missing")

    return PV, R, N, FV


# Program starts here
if __name__ == "__main__":
    PV, R, N, FV = input_values()

    if FV is None:
        FV = PV + (PV * N * R) / 365
    elif PV is None:
        PV = FV - (FV * N * R) / 365
    elif R is None:
        R = (FV - PV) / (N * PV) * 365
    elif N is None:
        N = (FV - PV) / (PV * R) * 365

    print("Present value:", round(PV, 2))
    print("Rate %:", round(R, 2))
    print("Time in days:", round(N, 2))
    print("Future value:", round(FV, 2))
```

First of all, it reads user input with the assumption that one of the values (PV, R, N, FV) is missing, then calculates that missing value and prints the output.

Type annotations are used to better understand what is happening.

Comment: Marvelous!!! Now I should study your coding till I understand it. lol

Answer (score 1):

You know the equation, so rearranging it to suit each combination of variables should be quite easy.

First, let's define a function that'll let us ask for an input. This function will allow the user to enter an input, and return `None` if it's not a `Decimal`. I suggest using the `decimal.Decimal` class for calculations with money because [floating point arithmetic can burn you](//docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

```
from decimal import *
def ask_input(prompt):
    ans = input(prompt + "(x if unknown) ")
    try:
        return Decimal(ans)
    except InvalidOperation:
        return None
```

Now, let's ask the user for their input:

```
PV = ask_input("Present value: ")
R = ask_input("Rate %: ")
N = ask_input("Time in days: ")
FV = ask_input("Future value: ")
```

Now, let's make sure only one of these is `None`:

```
num_unknowns = [PV, R, N, FV].count(None)
if num_unknowns != 1:
    print(f"I can handle only one unknown variable. You entered {num_unknowns}")
else:
    if FV is None:
        FV = PV + (PV * N * R) / 365
        print(f"FV = {FV:.2f}")
    elif PV is None:
        PV = FV / (1 + N * R / 365)
        print(f"PV = {PV:.2f}")
    elif N is None:
        # TODO: rearrange formula to calculate N
        print(f"N = {N:.2f} days")
    elif R is None:
        # TODO: rearrange formula to calculate R
        print(f"R = {R:.2f}%")
```

(Rearranging the equation is left as an exercise for the reader)